# How to install a specific version of Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I want to install Angular 4.3.1 or 4.4.6 or something like that. Currently I am using Angular cli version 1.4.1. When I provide the command it install the latest Angular 5 version and latest Angular 5 run properly.

```
ng new myproject
```

How to I create Angular 4.4.6 version. I have tried to change in package.json file and provide this command.

```
npm install
```

The command execute without any errors. When I try to run I am getting the following errors.

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I have also tries to delete the node_modules folder and run npm install command again. But the same errors. So my question is what is the proper way to install Angular 4 version?

Comment: looks like the problem is the node version installed, not the angular.

Comment: The Node version is 8.7.0

Comment: Before you running 'npm install' delete 'node_modules'

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067532/2275011

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is caused by incompatibilities of the versions in your package.json. Try this:

1. Delete node_modules dir from your project
2. Replace the dependencies and devDependencies sections in your package.json with the following:

   `"dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
       "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "@angular/cli": "1.4.0",
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
       "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
       "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
       "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
       "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
       "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
       "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
       "karma": "~1.7.0",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
       "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
       "protractor": "~5.1.2",
       "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
       "tslint": "~5.3.2",
       "typescript": "~2.3.3"
     }`

   3. Run npm install